# On a linear diophantine equation.

Tags: number-theory

Given coprime $A>2,B>2$ supposing $m$ and $n$ are solutions to diophantine equation
$$Am+Bn = cAB$$ where $|c|<\min(A,B)$ then is it true that $\max(|m|,|n|)>\min(A,B)$ holds always?

Comment: It's not true. Take $A=B=1, c=0$ and $m=n=0$.

Comment: I think definition of coprimality forbids $A=B=1$. can someone please clarify?

Comment: @ErickWong so am I right?

Comment: For me comprime just means $gcd(A,B)=1$. I think you need $c\neq 0$, otherwise we still have the solutions $m=n=0$. Furthermore, you should exclude $c=\pm 1$, otherwise we have the solutions $m=\pm B, n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ solve $Am+Bn = cAB$, where $1 < \vert c \vert < \min(A,B)$.

As $c\neq 0$ we have that not both $m$ and $n$ can be zero. W.l.o.g. assume that $m\neq 0$.

From our equation we get

$$ Am = B(cA - n).$$

As $A,B$ are coprime, we get that $B \ \vert \ m$, which implies  $\vert m \vert \geq B$ (as $m\neq 0$).

If $ m = \pm B$ the above equation implies

$$ A = \pm (cA-n).$$

From this we get

$$ n = A (\pm c - 1).$$

As $c\notin \{ 0, \pm 1\}$ we get $\vert n \vert > A.$

Thus

$$ \max(\vert m \vert, \vert n \vert) \geq \vert n \vert > A \geq \min(A,B).$$